# A complex vector function $\mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb C^3$, interpretation?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Say I have a vector function with complex components, $A:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb C^3$, ie. 
$$
A(x)=(A_1(x),A_2(x),A_3(x)),
$$
where $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$.

Does this mean the components are the following
\begin{align}
A_1:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{C}, \quad A_1(x)=u_1(x)+iv_1(x)\\
\text{where} \quad u_1,v_1:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb R\\
A_2:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{C}, \quad A_2(x)=u_2(x)+iv_2(x)\\
\text{where} \quad u_2,v_2:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb R\\
A_3:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{C}, \quad A_3(x)=u_3(x)+iv_3(x)\\
\text{where} \quad u_3,v_3:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb R
\end{align}
?

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: Yes, only take $u_k(x) = \Re(A_k(x))$ and  $v_k(x) = \Im(A_k(x))$.